# How to change the excel path for an export to excel ssis package

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have an SSIS package to export data to an excel file.

I  now removed the excel file from the folder I originally had and put it in a new folder.

I see that the package is sending an error. "Package Validation Error". I would like to know if there is a way to change the destination 
   path of the excel file within the ssis package

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the DelayValidation property to True for both the Excel Connection Manager and the Data Flow Task where you expect to use the file.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48963/ssis-connection-string-expression-at-run-time-and-during-execution/48985#48985

Within your Excel Connection Manager, in the Properties menu, you can apply an Expression that controls the file location.

Comment: can you assist I can not find where to set the properties of the excel connection manager for love nor money! I right click the connection / then properties then have nothing on the screen that reference properties - see here - http://bit.ly/11ICEUo - any assistance really appreciated!!